# Haskell Infinite Type

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to get the code below working. It's a finite state machine where I pass in a function-as-next-state. The function is called with `r` and returns a list of results + the next function-as-next state. Keep on calling until the list runs out, and return the concatenation of the results. The monad is an error monad to allow me to throw an error if needed.

```
fsm f []     = return []
fsm f (r:rs) = do
    (xs, f') <- f r
    rest     <- fsm f' rs
    return $ xs ++ rest
```

The error is:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t1 = t0 -> m0 ([a0], t1)
In the first argument of `fsm', namely f'
```

I've seen the infinite type error before and I understand the way around it is to wrap a type with a `newtype`. But I cannot figure out how to get this done.

Can someone point out the insight?

Comment: WHat is the type of `f`? Can you write it down?

Comment: It would be `f :: String -> m ([String], t)` where `t` would be the type of `f`. I understand this is why it is an infinite type but cannot figure out how to wrap it up correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
newtype F m = F { unF :: String -> m ([String], F m) }

fsm :: (Monad m) => F m -> [String] -> m [String]
fsm f []     = return []
fsm f (r:rs) = do
    (xs, f') <- unF f r
    rest     <- fsm f' rs
    return $ xs ++ rest
```

You are right that you need to use a `data` or `newtype` any time you want a recursive type.

In reply to your comment, here's how you would implement your `dup` function:

```
dup :: (Monad m) => F m
dup = F dup' where dup' xs = return ([xs, xs], F dup')
```

... or you could split it up into two separate definitions if you prefer.

Note that if you are not sure what the type signature should be, just enable the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension and the compiler will not complain and correctly infer the top-level type for you.

Comment: Hi Gabriel -- sorry, thought I could carry on, but I'm stuck again. Tried a simple `f`: `dup' xs = return ([xs, xs], FSM dup')`. Works. Then when I tried `dup = FSM dup'` so that I can feed it into `fsm`, it gives me a monomorphism error. What am I missing now?

Comment: Don't worry!  I updated my question showing you how to implement your `dup` function.